# How do I change the default URL for Logstash running under docker?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash

I am attempting to run an elasticsearch cluster with Kibana and Logstash using docker-compose.

The problem I'm running into is that Logstash keeps looking for the elastic search DB hostname as http://elasticsearch:9200.  Here's an example of the logstash output.

```
logstash    | [2021-08-23T15:30:03,534][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Marking url as dead. Last error: [LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError] Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch {:url=>http://elasticsearch:9200/, :error_message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch", :error_class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError"}
logstash    | [2021-08-23T15:30:03,540][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ResolutionFailure] elasticsearch"}
```

I'm also attaching my docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic

  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.14.0
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic

  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.14.0
    container_name: kib01
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: '["http://es01:9200","http://es02:9200","http://es03:9200"]'
    networks:
      - elastic
logstash:
    image: logstash:7.14.0
    environment:
        ELASTICSEARCH_HOST: localhost
    container_name: logstash
    hostname: localhost
    ports: 
      - 9600:9600
      - 8089:8089

    volumes:
        - ./logstash/logstash.yml
        - ./logstash/pipelines.yml
        - ./logstash/data
    command: --config.reload.automatic
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx1g -Xms1g"
    links:
        - es01:es01
    depends_on:
        - es01
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

For some reason, putting the host into the docker compose yaml file doesn't seem to work.  Where should I go to point logstash to locahost rather than 'elasticsearch'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Logstash has any such variable `ELASTICSEARCH_HOST`... Plus, `localhost` would refer to the Logstash container itself, not something else. And don't set `hostname: localhost` for a container...

You have no container/service named `elasticsearch`, you have `es01-3`, thus why its unable to connect, (notice that Kibana uses the correct addresses) and you'd modify that address in the Logstash config/pipeline files